# XML file parsing in Java displaying error details

Tags: java, xml, parsing, numbers, line

1. While parsing an XML data file It would be really useful if one could point out the 
   line number (or even better if you could also point to some other higher level indicator 
   like the Tag) where validation failed.
2. Continue parsing the rest of the file and report multiple errors on a single run.

How to do the above while using Java?

## Example XML data file

```
<interface id="NewDesignPageCreation" title="NewDesignPageCreation" type="Interface">
    <structure>
      <part id="main" class="label"/> 
      <part id="topNarrowPanel" class="horizontalContainer"/> 
      <part id="dummyButton22" class="button" /> 
    </structure> 
    <layout id="NewDesignPageCreationLayout"> 
      <part id="main" height="99%" width="99%" left="1px" top="1px" position="absolute"/> 
      <part id="topNarrowPanel" height="30px" width="100%" left="10px" top="10px" position="absolute" parent_id="main"/> 
    </layout> 
</interface>
```

Comment: Are you talking about an XML file which is completely invalid as XML, one which is invalid in terms of failing its DTD, or one which is invalid in some other way? An example of the kind of failure would be useful.

Comment: I meant invalid with reference to DTD

Comment: Again, editing your question with an example would make this simpler. (If you've already got the code you're using for validation, that would help too.)

Comment: <interface id="NewDesignPageCreation" title="NewDesignPageCreation" type="Interface">
 <structure>
  <part id="main" class="label"/>
  <part id="topNarrowPanel" class="horizontalContainer"/> 
  <part id="dummyButton22" class="button" />   
 </structure>
 <layout id="NewDesignPageCreationLayout">
  <part id="main" height="99%" width="99%" left="1px" top="1px" position="absolute"/>
  <part id="topNarrowPanel" height="30px" width="100%" left="10px" top="10px" position="absolute" parent_id="main"/>       
 </layout>
</interface>

Comment: Again, please *edit your question*. Don't put the XML in comments - put it in your *question*. (Use the "edit" link at the bottom of the question.) Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the XMLReader interface for parsing, you can supply an ErrorHandler, and the line/column information for the errors is notified to your ErrorHandler.